If a diagonally-dominant matrix is similar to a positive-definite matrix, is the positive-definite matrix also diagonally-dominant?
Considering a diagonally-dominant matrix $\mathbf{A}=(\mathit{a}{_i}{_j}){_n}{_×}\mathit{_n}$ is similar to a symmetric positive-definite matrix $\mathbf{B}$. Is $\mathbf{B}$ also diagonally-dominant? And why?

$$
A=\pmatrix{{11+3\sqrt{13}\over2}&0\cr0&{11-3\sqrt{13}\over2}\cr}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
B=\pmatrix{10&3\cr3&1\cr}
$$
